# Как можно запоминать объекты на картинке, используя нейронные сети?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Допустим, что идет съемка улицы в режиме реального времени, на видео - улица, с левой стороны которой идут люди на правую, НО у всех людей разная скорость и съемка не обязательно ведется сверху, то-есть возможно закрытие телом одним человеком другим. Человек, который начал идти первым, может быть догнанным другим человеком и когда он его перегонит(и закроет своим силуетом первого человека), как программе узнать, что человек позади - именно первый человек? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать с помощью Python? Я полный новичек в нейронных сетях и тому подобных вещах, любая помощь очень поможет.

Comment: Можно сделать предположение, что скорость объектов не меняется.  Тогда измеряете/оцениваете скорость объектов до наложения и после.  И в соответствии с результатами присваиваете им метки. Можно еще для каждого объекта выбрать дескриптор (например, наиболее насыщенный цвет элемента одежды).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, можете начать отсюда:

```
https://habr.com/ru/company/recognitor/blog/505694/
https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-with-neural-networks-a4e2c46b4491
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-detect-objects-in-real-time-using-opencv-and-python-c1ba0c2c69c0
https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-9dc039a2596b
```

По прочтению этих статей вы возможно поймете, что чтобы реализовать "это" надо не Python знать, а пару лет отдать изучению Machine Learning и Computer Vision. Ну и уж потом думать, как такое можно реализовать на любом доступном инструменте.

Answer (score 1):

Используя нейронные сети можно опознать факт наличия человека на изображении с координатой. Для того, чтобы осуществить трекинг, я бы порекомендовал использовать [метод K ближайших векторов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), наложив координаты с двух кадров на одну плоскость

[image: k-means]

В качестве нейронки для получения самих координат, посмотрите [этот проект](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/yolo-screencapture-python)